# How do I cut and paste an image onto a PDF document?

Tags: pdf

I've done it the traditional cut/paste way, but when the image opens on the PDF doc, it is tiny and unreadable. No matter how I try to manipulate the pasted image, it will not fit on the PDF form correctly.

Comment: PDF is intended as a way to store and preserve the appearance of a document.  It isn't really designed as a document creation medium.  You can do limited editing to a PDF, but it is not very robust.

Comment: Hi Do you want to paste image similar to a word document?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this.
It is a not a straight forward way of adding images as you would do with MS Word or something similar.
Follow the below steps to add images to a PDF file:
Step-1: Copy the picture that you want to add to PDF to the Clipboard
Step-2: Open Acrobat (I'm assuming you have Acrobat) and paste the image using the stamp tool (`Tools->Comment and Markup->Stamps->Paste Clipboard Image as Stamp Tool`). See image below
[image]